# Employee AND Manager

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have data with: `EMPID, NAME, MANAGER_ID`

[image: Like this]

I need to return: `EMPID, NAME, COLLEAGUE_ID`

`COLLEAGUE_ID` will be a list of people with the same manager as the person in `EMP_ID`

[image: Like this]

Any help would be great. Even if its just the name of the type of function i need to accomplish this.

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: I'd suggest going through any tutorial on SQL JOINs, this should be covered much more comprehensively there

Comment: Tip: Reasons not to use images are [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/92546).

Answer (score 1):

This sounds basically like a `cross join`.  But because managers are not included in your table, you also need `union all`:

```
select t1.emp_id, t1.name, t2.emp_id as colleague
from t t1 join
     t t2
     on t1.manager = t2.manager and t1.emp_id <> t2.emp_id
union all
select t1.emp_id, t1.name, t1.manager
from t;
```